# add number to address in an address register assembly language

Tags: arrays, assembly

I want to learn how to map an array in assembly language (Motorola 68k).

I am trying to move a value in a data register D1 to memory, and the address in memory I want to move the values to is held in A1. Also, it is worth to mention that A1 address points to a declared storage with size of 500 bytes, which should be plenty of space for what I want to do. I try the following:

```
moveq     #0,D1 *moves value of 0 into D1

loop:

cmpi.w    #10,D1 *checks if D1 is less than 10, else branch out to done
bge       done

move.w    D1,(A0) *moves 0 into address that A0 points to 



*then I get stuck here. I want to increment the address value ++ 
*(or whatever size I have to, which I am guessing is 1 word, since I am using words), so 
*that my values in memory are contiguous up to ten in memory, 
*such as 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a



addq.w    #1,D1  *D1 incremented by 1
bra       loop  *branch to loop again

done:

      break
```

Could you guys help me please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 68k has a postincrement addressing mode, which you specify with a trailing `+`, as in:

```
move.w    D1,(A0)+
```

Quoting from the M68000 Programmer's Reference Manual:

> After the operand address is used, it is incremented by one, two, or four depending on the size of the operand: byte, word, or long word, respectively.

Comment: if you can, could you please help me out with this question as well please? thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219242/moving-raw-hex-to-memory-in-assembly-language