# Moving raw hex to memory in assembly language

Tags: arrays, assembly

I am trying to move say, the number 24 in hex to the memory location held in my address register A0. I am programming with the Motorola 68k assembly language.

The thing is that I am not sure how to add an immediate piece of data to memory (with address A0).

which command could I use to do so?

I tried addq.b but I dont think its doing its' thing...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking in my copy of "Programming the M68000" King and Knight, gives a clue. I can't check this as my Atari ST monitor is a bit out action.

```
ORG       $1000
MOVEA.L   #$2000,A0    Load Start address
MOVE.L    #$24,D2      Load the value
MOVE.L    D2,(A0)      Store the value
```